# How to combine multiple char variables with space separated values in a struct variable?

Tags: c, string, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct donor
    {
        char *name;
        char *code ;
        char *donor;
        char *ship;
        char *quant;
        char *id;
        char *string;
        struct donor *link;
    } ;

typedef struct donor Donor;
char box[20];
int main(){
    Donor *node = malloc(sizeof(Donor));
    node-> id = strdup("GA");
    node-> code = strdup("HI");
    node-> donor = strdup("TO");
    node-> ship = strdup("GD");
    node-> quant = strdup("UT");

    // Combine all nodes' value into box.
    sprintf(box, "%s %s %s %s %s", node->id, node->code, node->donor, node->ship, node->quant);
    printf("%s", box);
    node->string = strdup(box);
    printf("%s", node->string);

}
```

I created a struct donor and assigned all nodes/variables a two-letter string. I want my node->string to store the combined "GA HI TO GD UT" string. I tried sprintf here to copy all nodes' values into char box, and node->string = strdup(box). But it doesn't output anything after that. Any ideas?

Comment: How many strings do you tell `sprintf` you want to print, and how many do you actually provide???

Comment: It's only 5. I've corrected it but the result is still the same, no output.

Comment: add a newline `"%s\n"`?

Comment: the code works fine with `-fsanitnize=undefined,address` and under Valgrind (though there are some leaks)

Answer (score 0):

3 minor modifications. I compiled and ran. So try this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct donor
        {
            char *name;
            char *code ;
            char *donor;
            char *ship;
            char *quant;
            char *id;
            char *string;
            struct donor *link;
        } ;

    typedef struct donor Donor;
    char box[20]= {'\0'};  /* force c string */
    int main(){
        Donor *node = malloc(sizeof(Donor));
        node-> id = strdup("GA");
        node-> code = strdup("HI");
        node-> donor = strdup("TO");
        node-> ship = strdup("GD");
        node-> quant = strdup("UT");

        // Combine all nodes' value into box.
        sprintf(box, "%s %s %s %s %s", node->id, node->code, node->donor, node- 
                                         >ship, node->quant);
        printf("%s\n", box);            /*request line output */
        node->string = strdup(box);
        printf("%s\n", node->string);   /*request line output */
        fflush(stdout);                 /*final attempt to force output*/

}
```

If you still get no output, the issue is not C. Either your tool chain, or corrupt library [re-install], or IDE configuration [run directly from a command prompt], or OS level issue.

```
My results:
c:\jim3\tmpp\lcc>tmpp
GA HI TO GD UT
GA HI TO GD UT
c:\jim3\tmpp\lcc>
```